# A program to refresh web page whenever clock ticks 12 AM or 12 PM

Tags: javascript

I have created a web based clock using javaScript. it outputs time in 12 hour format and needs to be refreshed pressing F5 whenever clock ticks 12 AM or 12 PM.

So i need a program to refresh the webpage automatically whenever the clock ticks 12 AM or PM .

I was checking my JS clock the output was

```
      Output: 11: 59 : 00 PM Sunday // 23 : 59 : 00
```

After few minutes I checked again

```
      Output 12 :  01 : 00 PM Sunday // 0 :  01 : 00
```

I had to refresh webpage to see changes
I want auto refresh program

Here is my code

```
    <body onload="autoref()">

    <script>

    function autoref(){
    var now = new Date();
    var h = now.getHours();
    var m = now.getMinutes();
    var s = now.getSeconds();

    if(h==0 && s==0){
    location.reload();
    }else if(h==12 && s==0){
    location.reload();
    }

    var trig = setTimeout(autoref,500);
    }

    </script>

    </body>
```

Any ideas!?

Thanks

Comment: What was your idea and the code you tried?

Comment: I don't see why you need a program to refresh the page. You can easily handle this in JS. Why not post your code and explain/expand upon what you really want. Which I assume has something to do with am/pm not updating.

Comment: Might help you to look at [window.location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) and also [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: @MichaelHobbs I want what u said... my clock not only has AM PM but also Day whenever clock ticks 12 AM  day name should change but i had to refresh the page to see the change so i want an automatic program to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got  answer myself sorry for disturbing you guys
Heres my code

```
<body onload="refresh()">

    <h1>
    Hello, Dcoder
    </h1>

    <div class="dcoder">

    </div>

 <script>


 function refresh(){
    var now = new Date();
    var h = now.getHours();
    var m = now.getMinutes();
    var s = now.getSeconds();

    var out = h+" : "+m+" : "+s;

    var trig = setTimeout(refresh,500);

    document.getElementsByClassName("dcoder")[0].innerHTML = out;

    if(h==12 && s==0){
        location.reload();
    }else if(h==0 && s==0){
        location.reload();
    }
    }



 </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code this is the best I can offer.

```
var amPm = undefined

function drawDisplay () {
    // code that draws your display
}

setInterval(()=>{
    var hour = (new Date()).getHours()
    if (hour === 0 && amPm !== 'am') {
        amPm = 'am'
        drawDisplay ()
    }
    if (hour === 12 && amPm !== 'pm') {
        amPm = 'pm'
        drawDisplay ()
    }
},1000)
```

Another way

```js
// code that draws your display
function drawDisplay() {
 var seconds = -1
 return ()=>{
  var date = new Date()
  if (date.getSeconds() > seconds || (date.getSeconds() === 0 && seconds === 59)) {
   seconds = date.getSeconds()
   console.log(date.toLocaleString())
  }
 }
}

setInterval(drawDisplay(),250)
```

Comment: your code will refresh the page every 250 milliseconds, which is wrong.
the questioner wants it to refresh on given time.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned "whenever", i take it that it must happen every day and have added code to check whether page is refreshed, to avoid continuous refresh.
Here is the code:
**Remember to accept the answer and click the upvote button if the answer satisfies you,
else give more information in the question (like, what have you done and then what are you getting), so that members here, can give right answers.**
**Also don't get demotivated with negative comments by experienced ones.**

```
<span id='spn'>
</span>
<script
    src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
    integrity='sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8='
    crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

<script>
//variable to check whether the page was refreshed or the page will keep on refreshing every second.
var vrefreshed=localStorage.getItem('refreshed');
if (typeof vrefreshed === 'undefined')
    vrefreshed = 0;

function time() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    if(vrefreshed==0 && ((h==23 && m==59 && s==59) || (h==11 && m==59 && s==59))){
        localStorage.setItem('refreshed', 1);
        vrefreshed=1;
        $('#spn').text('page is refreshed.');
        location.reload();
    }else{
        if(vrefreshed==1 && ((h==23 && m==59 && s==59) || (h==11 && m==59 && s==59))){
            // do nothing
        }else{
            localStorage.setItem('refreshed', 0);
            vrefreshed=0;
            $('#spn').text('page will be refreshed at 12 or 24.');
        }
    }
}
//call time() function every 1000 milliseconds i.e. every second.
setInterval(time, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: @sifr_dot_in JS hours are 0-23 not 1-24